# Visual Studio C# Toolbox Not Working On Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am new to Visual Studio in general, but i am having issues with creating even the most basic Windows Forms Applications in Visual Studio C#. I have researched my error around the internet and have found nothing, and i am wondering if i missed something in installation of Visual Studio C#. Whenever i try to add something from the toolbox into the Application, i get an error like this (Keep in mind I am new to this so don't come down on me too hard in the responses if its a simple issue.):
Failed to create component 'Component' (It says 'Component' each time, no matter what I attempt to create in the application.). The Error message follows: 'The toolbox item could not be retrieved from the toolbox. Make sure that the assembly that contains the toolbox is correctly installed (What does this mean). The toolbox item raised the following error: The toolbox item cannot be deserialized due to lack of serializer.

Comment: Try To Re-install your VS 2010. If Error exist again maybe there is a problem on your installer.

Answer (score 3):

See if either of the suggestions listed on this page (under the Workarounds tab) help.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/105780/cannot-drag-control-from-windows-forms-toolbox-onto-form

Especially the suggestion to right click inside the toolbox and select the "Reset Toolbox" option. If you had anything special installed, this will probably remove it, but it sounds like you're just getting into things so hopefully the only result is that you'll actually be able to *use* the toolbox and not get the error. :)

Edit:

Okay, let's try something else. Close out of Visual Studio, go into your app data directory on the hard drive (most easily found by just typing *%appdata%* in the address bar and pressing enter) and look for Microsoft/VisualStudio/10.0 and then rename 10.0 to 10.0b or something. Open a command prompt and navigate to c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\common7\ide. Once there, try running:

```
devenv /setup
devenv /resetsettings
```

Reopen VS2010 and see if the toolbox is still misbehaving.

Comment: Um, Im not sure if im doing something wrong but when i press choose items it opens a window that only has one item in it, which is called component. I cant close out of that window no matter what i push, so i have to force quit Visual Studio. And if i just do the Reset Toolbox thing it doesnt solve this issue. :(

Comment: It cant regonize the devenv thing (PS i dont understand Command Prompt at all, but im trying to figure it out a bit one command at a time, so could you explain what all that means?)

Comment: Haha i know how to open the command prompt and i figured out how to navigate to places on my own. But thanks anyway for that, i didnt know till you told me i needed to navigate somewhere and  I looked it up, and i got to those places, the commands did not work however.

Comment: I reinstalled it like a few days ago for other reasons, it had the issues before and after installation. It used to work just fine in C++ Visual Studio, but since than i have lost he ability to create projects for no apparent reason -.- sometimes i hate technology :(, thank you again for bearing with me the whole time. :)